# How to reduce the variability in Android camera shutter lag?

Tags: android, android-camera

Given a known periodic motion (e.g., walking), I'd like to take a full resolution snapshot at the same point in the motion (i.e., the same time offset within different periods). However on the Nexus S (currently running OS 4.1.1 but the same was true of previous OS versions), I'm seeing so much variability in the shutter lag that I cannot accurately plan the timing of the snapshot. Here is a histogram of the shutter lags of 50 photographs. (I measured the shutter lag with one System.nanoTime() just before Camera.takePicture() and another System.nanoTime() at the beginning of the shutter callback. The camera lens was consistently covered to remove any variability due to lighting.)

[image]

Is there anything I can do in the application to reduce this shutter lag variability? (In this application, the mean lag can be any duration but the standard deviation must be small ... much smaller than the 0.5 s standard deviation of the shutter lags shown in the above histogram.) I'm hoping someone has a clever suggestion. If I don't get any suggestions, I'll post a feature request in the Android bug tracker.

UPDATE:
I turned off auto-focus (by setting focus to infinity) following RichardC's suggestion at https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/WaHhTicKRA0
It helped, as shown in the following histogram. Any ideas to reduce the shutter lag variability even more?

[image]

UPDATE 2:
I disabled the remaining auto parameters: white balance, scene mode, flash. The following histogram of shutter lag time variability seems to be about as good as it gets for a Nexus S running OS 4.1.1. It would be nice to have much less variability in the shutter lag time, perhaps by specifying an optional minimum shutter lag time in Camera.takePicture() which would delay the shutter if it were ready before the specified minimum. I've posted a feature request to the Android issue tracker. If you are also interested in getting the feature, "star" it at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35785

[image]

Comment: any thoughts on doing this as a video capture stream and capturing periodic frames?  You do however say "full resolution snapshot" which means I think a video stream won't work for you because of lower res.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would gladly give up some image resolution for better image timing. I haven't yet explored that option much because even a video preview image slows down my motion detection/UI too much. This may be just the excuse I needed to get an Android phone with a multi-core processor. :*)

Comment: Did this ever go anywhere now that new hardware is out? I have variability on the order of 400 milliseconds using a HTC One, but my onShutter callback resides in the class with the main activity.

Comment: I don't know if the shutter lag has decreased recently. (I moved on to other tasks.)

Answer (score 0):

1. what's the x axis and what's the y axis?
2. you can use low level coding (like NDK/renderscript) instead of using java .
3. you might be able to change the settings of the camera to make it faster .

Comment: Thanks. The y axis of the histogram is the count of shutter lag times that fall into 0.2 second bins. The x axis is nanoseconds. I plan to eventually use renderscript for some calculation intensive portions of the application but I wasn't aware that it could help with controlling hardware like the camera.

Comment: Pardon me. The bin size of the histograms is actually 0.02 seconds (not 0.2 seconds as I wrote).

Comment: good luck , and please let us know if and how you've succeeded to make it even faster.  i've heard of a camera mod on an Omega ROM for SGS3 that claims to be faster and have even shorter shutter lag , but i can't see the difference since the device is fast already.